# In a <table>, how to get the <th> right above some <td> when the <th>s all have different colspan?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a project that generates on the backend a table which contains the months in the first line and the days of that months in the row below (see image).

[image: table]

When I click on a date cell, I need to get the name of the month from the `<th>` above the clicked `<td>`. The problem is that the `<th>`s all have different `colspan` values. I can't change the backend script, so I need to do this client-side with JavaScript.

Here there is an example of the table, and a function I started to handle the click:

```js
var day = -1;
function selectDay(day) {
 console.log(day.innerHTML);
 console.log(day.attributes.alt.nodeValue);
}
```

```css
.calendar {

    position: absolute;
    width: 98vw;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    margin-right: 1vw;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid black;

}

body {

    font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;

}

.calendar {

    white-space: nowrap;

}

.calendar table tr th, td {

    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 21px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;

}
```

```html
<div class="calendar"><!--class="active"-->
<table>
<tbody><tr> <th colspan="24" style="background-color: #1b1bef ;">Settembre 2019</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #4112a0 ;">Ottobre 2019</th> <th colspan="30" style="background-color: #761ca2 ;">Novembre 2019</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #b23593 ;">Dicembre 2019</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #ed008c ;">Gennaio 2020</th> <th colspan="29" style="background-color: #d0191b ;">Febbraio 2020</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #f06730 ;">Marzo 2020</th> <th colspan="30" style="background-color: #f08622 ;">Aprile 2020</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #e9eb28 ;">Maggio 2020</th> <th colspan="30" style="background-color: #b4e742 ;">Giugno 2020</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #5fc650 ;">Luglio 2020</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #1fa5a6 ;">Agosto 2020</th> <th colspan="30" style="background-color: #1b1bef ;">Settembre 2020</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #4112a0 ;">Ottobre 2020</th> <th colspan="30" style="background-color: #761ca2 ;">Novembre 2020</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #b23593 ;">Dicembre 2020</th> </tr> <tr> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> 
</tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

If anyone can help to make this work, thanks.

Comment: Please do not try and bypass the restrictions on pasting links to code. Instead click [edit(https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57821426/edit) then the `[<>]` stack snippet editor and post the code HERE instead

Comment: Please don't work around the error message by formatting non-code text as code. Instead, actually include the code you are working on in the question. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make that happen.

Comment: the reason why i did the work around is because a. i'm an idiot and i don't know how to make it propperly work b. if you look at the codee is realy long and would be realy realy messy to put it in the main question . ..

Comment: @EnryFrafranci Usually (although not always) it's quite possible to remove most of the code except the part that causes error.

Comment: and maybe you are running on chrome, because on firefox it works and that is not the problem in this question . . .

Comment: If you have control over the HTML, you should put the month information into the `class` atrribute of the `td` tags (or day-month as `id` even). Then you can easily look at that in your handler.

Comment: i considered that, but the problem is that i would have to rebuild the hole thing, wich is not the best, and i would prefer do everything in the front end

Comment: In my experience, fixing a problem at the root, instead of doctoring the symptoms pays out in the long run.

Comment: function selectDay(day) {
      /* counts the column index of the clicked day */
      var col = 0;
      var el = day;
      while((el = el.previousSibling) != null ) 
        col++;
      col++;
      col/=2;
      
      /* use the colspan values to determine in which month we are */
      var months = document.querySelectorAll('th');
      var j = 0;
      while(col > 0){
        col -= months[j].getAttribute('colspan');
        j++;
      }
      var month = months[j-1];

     console.log(day.innerHTML+month.innerHTML);
    }

Comment: thank you, thant's what i needed. maybe make it an answer so i can approve it @FrançoisHuppé

Comment: i tried but its on hold ! Maybe we could edit the question a little bit.

Comment: darn it, do you know how to ask to remove it, because i don't . . .

Comment: @EnryFrafranci finally they removed the hold after i edited !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```js
var day = -1;
function selectDay(day) {
  // count the column index of the clicked day
  var col = 0;
  var el = day;
  while((el = el.previousSibling) != null ) 
    col++;
  col++;
  col/=2;
  
  // use the colspan values to determine in which month we are
  var months = document.querySelectorAll('th');
  var j = 0;
  while(col > 0){
    col -= months[j].getAttribute('colspan');
    j++;
  }
  var month = months[j-1];

 console.log(day.innerHTML+month.innerHTML);
}
```

```css
.calendar {

    position: absolute;
    width: 98vw;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    margin-right: 1vw;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid black;

}

body {

    font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;

}

.calendar {

    white-space: nowrap;

}

.calendar table tr th, td {

    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 21px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;

}
```

```html
<div class="calendar"><!--class="active"-->
<table>
<tbody><tr> <th colspan="24" style="background-color: #1b1bef ;">Settembre 2019</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #4112a0 ;">Ottobre 2019</th> <th colspan="30" style="background-color: #761ca2 ;">Novembre 2019</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #b23593 ;">Dicembre 2019</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #ed008c ;">Gennaio 2020</th> <th colspan="29" style="background-color: #d0191b ;">Febbraio 2020</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #f06730 ;">Marzo 2020</th> <th colspan="30" style="background-color: #f08622 ;">Aprile 2020</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #e9eb28 ;">Maggio 2020</th> <th colspan="30" style="background-color: #b4e742 ;">Giugno 2020</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #5fc650 ;">Luglio 2020</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #1fa5a6 ;">Agosto 2020</th> <th colspan="30" style="background-color: #1b1bef ;">Settembre 2020</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #4112a0 ;">Ottobre 2020</th> <th colspan="30" style="background-color: #761ca2 ;">Novembre 2020</th> <th colspan="31" style="background-color: #b23593 ;">Dicembre 2020</th> </tr> <tr> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)" alt="something somethig"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 1 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 2 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 3 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 4 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 5 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 6 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 7 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 8 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 9 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 10 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 11 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 12 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 13 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 14 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 15 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 16 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 17 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 18 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 19 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 20 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 21 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 22 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 23 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 24 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 25 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 26 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 27 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 28 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 29 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 30 </td> <td onclick="selectDay(this)"> 31 </td> 
</tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The console error is quite clear

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined

which is `day.attributes.alt.nodeValue`

There is no valid attribute called `alt` for a table cell, so Chrome removes it

You likely want to generate that table using script

Here is how you need to get the data.

1. Wrap the tbody around the tbody and have a thead too
2. Remove the onclick from all cells
3. Listen for the click on the tbody and look at the cell clicked

```js
const getDays = (d) =>  new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth()+1,0,12,0,0,0).getDate();
const aDay = 24*60*60*1000;
const monthNames = ["Gennaio","Febbraio","Marzo","Aprile","Maggio","Giugno","Luglio","Agosto","Settembre","Ottobre","Novembre","Dicembre"];
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const today = new Date();
  const end = new Date(today.getFullYear()+1,12,1,12,0,0,0).getTime(); // next year - quick hack due to summertime?
  let headers = [];
  let cells = [];
  headers.push(`<th colspan="${getDays(today)-today.getDate()}" class="${monthNames[today.getMonth()]}">${monthNames[today.getMonth()]}  ${today.getFullYear()}</th>`)
  for (let i=today.getTime()+aDay; i<=end; i+=aDay) {
    let d = new Date(i);
    const month = monthNames[d.getMonth()];
    if (i>today.getTime() && d.getDate()===1) {
      headers.push(`<th colspan="${getDays(d)}" class="${month}">${month} ${d.getFullYear()}</th>`);
    }
    cells.push(`<td data-year="${d.getFullYear()}" data-month="${month}">${d.getDate()}</td>`);
  }    
  document.getElementById("tbh").innerHTML=headers.join("");
  document.getElementById("tbd").innerHTML=cells.join("");
  document.getElementById("tbd").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.tagName === "TD") {
      console.log(
        tgt.textContent,
        tgt.getAttribute("data-month"),
        tgt.getAttribute("data-year")
      );
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.calendar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 98vw;
  margin-left: 1vw;
  margin-right: 1vw;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.calendar {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.calendar table tr th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 21px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
}

.Gennaio   { background-color: #1b1bef }
.Febbraio  { background-color: #4112a0 }
.Marzo     { background-color: #761ca2 }
.Aprile    { background-color: #b23593 }
.Maggio    { background-color: #ed008c }
.Giugno    { background-color: #d0191b }
.Luglio    { background-color: #f06730 }
.Agosto    { background-color: #f08622 }
.Settembre { background-color: #e9eb28 }
.Ottobre   { background-color: #b4e742 }
.Novembre  { background-color: #5fc650 }
.Dicembre  { background-color: #1fa5a6 }
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <!--class="active"-->
  <table>
    <thead id="tbh">
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbd">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: this is all great and fine, but i need to also be able to return the month and the year(it's in italian in the example) that are present on the first line . . .

Comment: Please see update - note you can set some data-event using an array too